# Resize window with responsive bootsrap image grid and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap grid layout that looks like the image below. The text section has the following CSS:

```
  height:720px;
```

The images have been inserted into the columns using the bootstrap `img-responsive` class.

When I re-size the browser window all images shrink and respond accordingly as it reaches the tablet media query breaking point however the text area because it has a defined height is causing problems.

How can I make that grey text box scale down like the images on window re-size but so that the text is still readable. Should I be using javascript?

[image]

## UPDATE#

Attached is my current code for the grid and the css any suggestions would be great.

## CSS / html

```
.home-row{
background: #e4e4e4;
height:720px;
}


.home-text{
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-indent: 0;
text-align: left;
font-family:HelveticaNeue;
text-transform: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-size: 1.9em;
letter-spacing: normal;

 }


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sx-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 main-txt home-row">
    <p class="home-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce                                  tincidunt dignissim nisi gravida dapibus. Vivamus mollis magna vel lacus pretium scelerisque. Nunc a nibh in nisi pharetra rutrum sit amet vel massa. Pellentesque molestie ex neque, 
      </p>
      <p>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class="home-text">
      sed commodo nisi condimentum nec. Nam fermentum libero sed pretium    scelerisque. Ut risus augue, fringilla maximus dui eget, malesuada laoreet    velit. Fusce sit amet tellus       lorem. Interdum
      </p>
      <p>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class="home-text">
   Cras interdum tortor id enim fermentum scelerisque. Praesent viverra       ante at pharetra elementum. 

      </p>
      <p>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class="home-text">
       Donec id mauris elementum, tincidunt ipsum nec, consectetur erat. Ut       nec erat et neque scelerisque fringilla. Sed sodales sem a arcu volutpat maximus     ac eget quam. In.
      </p>
      <p>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class="home-text">
      . Praesent viverra ante at pharetra elementum. 
         <br>
       
      </p>
      
</div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sx-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 no-pad">
         <img src="img/panel-blue.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-sx-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3  no-pad">
     <img src="img/light-house.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 .col-md-offset-6 no-pad">
     <img src="img/panel-staff.png" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-pad">
    <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-pad">
   <img src="img/pannel-tall.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-pad">
  <img src="img/panel-red-img.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-pad">
    <img src="img/pannel-compas-smal.png" class="img-responsive">

    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 no-pad">
  <img src="img/panel-large.png" class="img-responsive">

   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: use @media queries and target your text section. Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: but how does that help the resize of the text section i would have to target a lot of media queries and change the font size and the height of the colum

Comment: JavaScript for that, maybe vertical scrollbar instead of decreasing font size?

Comment: use relative instead of absolute sizing.e.g. `em` or `%` for your box and the font. combine this with media queries.

Comment: attached is the code

Answer (score 0):

Change height: 720px; to

```
height:50%;
```

I don't have your code so I can't see how you designed the layout but changing the height from a set px to a percentage of the screen should fix the problem.